# How to compute lot size percentually having a stop loss on python using Metatrader

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, metatrader5

I am trying to compute lot size having stop loss (as price) but the lot size ends up quite big and eventually, I get an error:

```
Error code: 10014
Error message: Invalid volume
```

My current code is:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

def calculate_lot_size(symbol, stop_loss_price):
    # Connect to the MetaTrader 5 terminal
    if not mt5.initialize():
        print("Failed to initialize MetaTrader 5")
        return None

    # Get the current account balance
    account_info = mt5.account_info()
    if account_info is None:
        print("Failed to retrieve account information")
        mt5.shutdown()
        return None

    account_balance = account_info.balance

    # Get the symbol's point value (minimum price change)
    symbol_info = mt5.symbol_info(symbol)
    if symbol_info is None:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve symbol information for {symbol}")
        mt5.shutdown()
        return None

    point_value = symbol_info.point

    # Calculate the maximum acceptable loss based on the account balance and stop loss price
    max_loss = account_balance * (symbol_info.last / stop_loss_price - 1)

    # Calculate the lot size based on the maximum acceptable loss and the point value
    lot_size = max_loss / point_value

    # Print the calculated lot size
    print(f"Lot size for {symbol}: {lot_size} lots")

    # Disconnect from the MetaTrader 5 terminal
    mt5.shutdown()

    return lot_size

# Example usage
symbol = "EURUSD"
stop_loss_price = 1.2000  # Stop loss price
lot_size = calculate_lot_size(symbol, stop_loss_price)
```

I believe that I am using the latest version of Metatrader5 which is 5.0.45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct solution:

```
risk_ticks = (price - sl) / symbol.trade_tick_size
size = risk_capital / (risk_ticks * symbol.trade_tick_value)
```